# How to Enhance the height difference of the experimental signal data?

Tags: signal-analysis, enhancement

I'm very new to signal processing. Is there any kind of method to enhance the signal of experimental data that I get from the experiment? Especially on the difference of y-axis. Thank you

[image: Surface Plasmon Resonance Experimental Data]
This signal is coming from the surface plasmon resonance experiment using gold colloidal to immobilize the gold thin layer, the Y-Axis is the intensity of how the signal response to the refraction index change and the "SIGNAL" measured by intensity differences and the X-Axis is time, so right now my signal response is pretty weak and recently my Professor ask me can I tried to enhance my weak signal without changing the experimental input or procedure.

Comment: You can – just multiply each value with a constant. That constant needs to be > 1. Is that really what you're asking?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I already try that, but is it okay? *about the ethic of signal processing. Is it not considered as data manipulation? By the way, I already try to add stochastic resonant to the dataset but I don't get how to increase the difference of y-axis.

Comment: Um are you sure *ethics* is the right word here? Really, you seem to be assuming we know a lot of things about your signal, and about where it comes from, what it means, and what you're planning to do with it. We know none of that – and we'll need to know **all** of that to help you. Please **significantly extend your question by editing it** to answer **all** these four things: 1. where does the signal come from? 2. where will the processed signal go to? 3. which problem is this signal processing supposed to solve? 4. are there any specific constraints to what processing should be done?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Oh ok thank you for your suggestion! I'll try to add more description to my question

Comment: well, OK, reading that: what's wrong with just multiplying? I mean, you should note down the factor, of course. I, however, doubt that what you write "enhance my weak signal" means that the *amplitude* needs to be higher, like you think it should be. Probably he wants the signal-to-noise ratio to be better! Is that intrepretation sensible?

Comment: What you need to also show is what the refraction change looks like with time.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Oh ok, I'll try to tell my Professor this Monday. Thank you for your suggestion, and I'll make sure to ask him what he really wants, but I think he really wants to increase the y-axis differences that he told me yesterday.

Comment: well, then it's just a multiplication. Write him an email today! Profs, in my experience, are kinda happy when they get concise questions that they can answer quickly at a time they choose, so less than an email a day is probably not considered too much, especially when it means that you can continue to work today and don't have to wait till Monday!